# How to fix CommonJS dependency warning on custom pipe file in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I've added a couple of modules to my angular.json JS dependencies section like this:

```json
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["angular2-wizard", "hammerjs", "moment-timezone"]
```

But I just upgraded everything and I'm getting another warning about a pipe I created that uses moment:

```
[webpack-dev-server] WARNING
/Users/mysite/client/src/app/pipes/time-zone.pipe.ts depends on 'moment'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
```

I tried adding the .ts filename to the list like below but I'm still getting the warning.

```json
"allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["angular2-wizard", "hammerjs", "moment-timezone", "time-zone"]
```

I also tried: "time-zone.pipe.ts" and "TimeZonePipe" which is the name of the class, but none seem to remove the warning.

How can I fix this?

```
import {
  Pipe,
  PipeTransform
} from '@angular/core';
import * as moment from 'moment';

@Pipe({
  name: 'timeZone'
})
export class TimeZonePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(dateUtc: Date, timeZone: string, momentFormat: string, convertJustTimeZone = false): string {
    const tempDateUtc = moment(dateUtc).utc(true);
    tempDateUtc.tz(timeZone, convertJustTimeZone);
    return tempDateUtc.format(momentFormat);
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you just need to add 'moment' to your `allowedCommonJsDependencies`?

Comment: You can safely ignore this one. There is also a way to disable the warning for a specific package. Do not remember how it was named. But it is set in angular.json

Comment: Adding moment to allowedCommonJS DEp.. worked, but should I be concerned doing this for later upgrades?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned `momentjs` is a CommonJS module, tree-shaking does not work well on CommonJS modules, that is why you got warning. See official link from Angular docs [How CommonJS is making your bundles larger](https://web.dev/commonjs-larger-bundles/).

So you have only two options: ignore this warning and continue using `momentjs` hoping that in the future they move to es6 modules or switch to another library like `luxon`.

Comment: Would it be easy to move to Luxon? I have lots of calls like this, moment().utc().isSameOrAfter(moment(this.event.dateUtc)) where I compare 2 datetimes using moment

Comment: `DateTime.fromISO("2014-08-06T09:10:16", { zone: "utc"}) >= DateTime.fromISO("2014-08-06T09:10:15", { zone: "utc"})` something like that.